# Get all members in a group on Ldap

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

How i get all members in a group on Ldap with java? I tried:

```
public List getListAdmin() {
    String base = "cn=admin, ou=group, dc=Google";
    return ldapTemplate.search(base, "(&(objectclass=person)(memberOf=admin))", new UtenteAttributeMapper());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the group DN, use a filter like:

```
(member=*)
```

You may need to verify that "member" is the correct attribute for you LDAP server implementation Some us "uniqueMember" or something else.

memberOf is no supported on all LDAP server implementations.

-jim

Comment: public List getAllContactAdmin() {
        String base = "cn=Administrators,ou=Group_test";
        String filter = "(member=*)";
        return ldapTemplate.search(base, filter, new UtenteAttributeMapper());
    }